# How can I tell when a device connects and disconnects from the network?

Tags: c#, networking, snmp, router, arp

I want to be able to arm/ disarm my surveillance software (open source - ispy) based on the wifi network presence of my mobile phone (wifi). Somehow I need ispy to detect that the mobile phone has connected to the wireless network to disarm the system and then also detect that it has disconnected so it can re-arm it.

I've been reading about SNMP (which I haven't been able to get working - i setup a listener on udp port 161 and set the trap manager to point to my pc and it doesn't send anything except for an initial "0?") and ARP (which I have been able to get working but it seems to be cached on my local PC and definitely not updated in real time).

I would much rather find a solution that relies on either a notification from the router (preferably not UPNP as I've found that to be crash prone) or via some network packet sniffing and not by continually polling the router for a list of connected devices. Any examples in c# would be awesome.

Comment: I hope there is no siren attached to the system, otherwise you're in for a very unpleasant wake up call in the middle of the night if it disconnects for some reason...

Comment: Haha, I thought that, battery dies on phone etc.

Comment: Yeah it's going to be an optional feature :)

Answer (score 1):

When a device connects, it'll broadcast DHCP requests which should be visible to every device connected to the router (it's unlikely that it'll squash re-broadcast on the wireless just because the internal port is going to answer it).

Disconnect is more difficult because you won't get anything when the device leaves.  You'll have to poll it continuously and note when it no longer responds.  Of course, you can just broadcast poll for something specific to the phone and know both when it arrives and leaves using only this.

There's a program called "blueproximity" that does similar using Bluetooth.  It's probably not what you want for your problem but you can look at it for ideas.

Comment: Thanks Brian, will check it out

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention it but since you talked about ARP I suppose device is under DHCP so we have to work with MAC address. That said why don't you use [Nmap](http://nmap.org/)? It is free, simple and already includes an XML output that can be easily parsed with C#. I actually did this, only I don't have code on this computer right now :/